# column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails error in simple membership mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

My point is to able to use SimpleMembership. Firstly, I created roles in my Global.asax.cs class.

```
        Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(new InitSecurityDb());
        UsersContext context = new UsersContext();
        context.Database.Initialize(true);
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection",
                 "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

        if (!roles.RoleExists("Manager"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Manager");
        }
        if (!roles.RoleExists("Developer"))
        {
            roles.CreateRole("Developer");
        }
```

and then I added a role to user according to user type. if user type is manager, I want to add the manager role to my user. my posted register action :

```
     public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
        if (membership.GetUser(model.UserName, false) == null)
        {
            membership.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
        }

        if(model.status == UserType.Manager)
        {
            if (!roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).Equals("Manager"))
            {
                roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { model.UserName }, new[] { "manager" });
            }
        }
        if (model.status == UserType.Developer)
        {
            if (!roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName).Equals("Developer"))
            {
                roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { model.UserName }, new[] { "developer" });
            }
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { UserName = model.UserName, Password = model.Password, firstName = model.firstName, lastName = model.lastName, Email = model.Email, status = model.status });

                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

in the "membership.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password)" line  in Register action  **I got below error :**

**An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'status', table 'MyApplication.dbo.UserProfile'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.**

My userProfile class

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen adınızı giriniz.")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen soyadınızı giriniz.")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen şifrenizi giriniz...")]

    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Lütfen e-posta adresinizi giriniz.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Lütfen e-posta adresinizi geçerli bir formatta giriniz.")]

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public UserType status { get; set; }
}
```

and finally my Register model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }


    public string firstName { get; set; }


    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public UserType status { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at your table and make sure that the column status is a nullable field. If it's a required field, you will get that error message if you try to enter a null value in there. I wanted to add this as a comment, but I don't have enough privileges to add comment.

Comment: in my register action, user had been created 2 times using membership.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password); and WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,...). maybe because of this reason I got a lot of error. I erased one of them and also I implemented your solution. Thanks.